# Why cant i edit my CSS on my Gitpod Workspace?

Tags: css, gitpod

Does anyone have any clue why gitpod will let me edit my html  side of things but my css page will not update anything when it comes to previewing the created page, I can literally delete all of my existing CSS rules and the preview of the page remains the same. No font changes taking effect, no colors. nothing for CSS seems to be working, Its all linked up properly with the href and rel . I am logged in (had to double check).

Answer (score 0):

can you try opening the preview in a dedicated browser tab and hard reload the page(in case it's some plain html+css+js project).